# GeoServer deployment

Tags: geoserver, java, apache, deployment

I've been trying to deploy GeoServer in a WAMP/Apache environment via a `.war` file. (GeoServer being downloaded as a web archive)

When I try to enter the address in the web browser, I get this:

[image: Image of directory browsing response of GeoServer request]

Has somebody already encountered the same issue ? Do you know the reason for such a failure ?

Answer (score 4):

You're running it under Apache and MySQL and PhP, but GeoServer is Java based.

What you want to do is to install Jetty or Tomcat, and then drop the .war into the appropriate place for that software to run the code in. If you want to go the extra mile, you can use a regular web-server (apache or nginx) as a reverse proxy, so that you remove the :8080 port component of the URL.

Or you can use the standard Windows installer: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/win_installer.html

Edit from the future: You can also use [Docker to run GeoServer](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver), which is the modern way!